# whitespace under td tag

Tags: html, css

I am using the foundation framework for emails

I have a [Test Page](http://mimsi.dk/foundation/picture-test/test.html). Just under the picture of the racoon, there is a whitespace,that I need to get removed, so there is only the picture. I set a height on 250px, which the picture is. I looked through my css, to see if some padding did this. But I did not find anything.

The foundation has a lot of CSS, so I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfvsdjo9/):

Can anybody see why there is a white line?

**Relevant HTML**

```
<table class="row background-color__yellow">
  <tr>
    <td class="center" align="center">
      <center>
        <table class="container">
          <tr>
            <td class="wrapper last">
              <table class="twelve columns background-color__yellow">
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-top: 30px;">
                    <h3 class="headline">Kære flet[navn] flet[efternavn]</h3>
                    <br/>
                    <span>Tak for din reservation på [Flet. Har du spørgsmål, er du velkommen til at kontakte os. Vi har åbent alle hverdage mellem kl. 8.30 og kl. 16.00.
                    </span>
                    <br><br>
                    <span>
                      Vi ønsker dig et rigtig dejligt ophold
                    </span>
                    <span>Med venlig hilsen</span>
                    <br/>
                    <span>Name</span>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <span>[flet if/else statement] PS: Det er gratis at blive medlem af vores gæsteklub, hvor du optjener point på ophold og får adgang til et væld af gode tilbud. </span>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <span>[flet]<a href="https://www.google.dk/benefits/login/">Klik her for at læse mere og tilmelde dig</a></span>
                    <br/><br/>

                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: middle` to the `a` that's wrapping the `img`.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/ewcyk34o/1/)

I've added a class to that `a` called `remove-space`, and I've styled it in the first line of the CSS.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. This one fitted very good for me, so I will accept yours. Best Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Put a **`style="line-height:0"`**
In the top `<td>` of the image and let me know if works.
cheers.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer, This solved the problem to. I choose to set a class on the a href as ovokuro suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class for td and remove line height of td

```
<html>
   <td class="remove_space">
       <a href="https://www.google.dk" target="_blank">
          <img width="500" height="250" src="http://animalhumanhealth.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/racoon1.png" alt="test"></a>
   </td>
</html>


<style>

table.twelve td.remove_space {
line-height: 0;
}

</style>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

The space comes from here :

```
body, table.body, p, td, th {
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display: inline-block` CSS property for the anchor tag surrounding the image.